# Displaying first few words of WordPress page in the nav

Tags: php, html, wordpress, nav

I'm wanting to display a WordPress nav that has the first few words of each page below it.

This is what I currently have:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&link_after=<span>FIRST FEW WORDS HERE</span>'); ?>
```

I want the output to be like:

```
<li><a href="#">Home<span>Welcome to the website</span></a></li>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Let's see the current html output from your `wp_list_pages()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could think of is doing this:

use `wp_get_pages` to get all the titles (or the ones you want), and then access the database with a query that will get each post using the title. So, for each title from the array the `get_pages` returned, you get a corresponding post. In either the SQL or the PHP use the `substring` method to get the first few words, and display however you want.

That's just the logic, I'm a bit rusty with code so I don't want to confuse you. I'll try if you don't get it...

Comment: I was thinking of doing it like this. I will run some tests and see how heavy it is on the database, I can imagine this could slow it down a little but I will see anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to put extra text inside the anchor by just passing params to `wp_list_pages`. You could however filter it and use `preg_replace`. For example...

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', function($data) {
    return preg_replace('/(<a[^>]+[^<]+)<\/a>/si', '\\1<span>FIRST FEW WORDS HERE</span></a>', $data);
});
```

Though I used `preg_replace()` you could also (and probably should) use `DomDocument` but this will work for most use cases.

Another way to do it would be to use a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make a custom loop and add it in the "index.php" file in your theme where you want to display it.

A quick example of how that would look:

```
<div id="nav"><ul>

 <!-- start the loop-->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <li class="nav_post">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
 <span><?php formatPreview(the_content()); ?></span></a>
 </li>

 <!-- stop the loop-->
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>No posts!</p>
 <?php endif; ?>

</ul></div>
```

the_permalink(), the_title(), and the_content() are the key players here to populate your custom nav with the post information. Then just add appropriate css for the nav ID, nav_post class, and h2/p and you're good to go! You'll probably want to hard stop the loop after a certain number of posts - I doubt you want every post listed in the nav!

You'll have to make the "formatPreview()" function separately to control how to format the preview of each post's content - but it shouldn't be hard to just substr the first few words!